# Is there any way to lock and unlock while dealing with multiple threads, without using inbuilt methods?

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, python-multithreading

```
import threading
x = 0
def test(lock):
    global x
    for i in range(10):
        lock.acquire()
        print(threading.current_thread())
        x+= 1
        lock.release()



def mt():
    lock = threading.Lock()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=test , args=(lock,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = test , args=(lock,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

mt()
print(x)
```

I am trying to learn multithreading in python. I used python inbuilt method to lock and unlock any process.
Can I do this without any inbuilt function?

Comment: two ways: 1. use 3rd locks, like redis lock; 2. use thread safety logic, especially avoid to use global variables.

Comment: hey, I am very new to this concept. can you please expand your answer?

Comment: It's a large topic, and it's hard to explain it clearly to a beginner. So, at first, you should use google to search what is "thread safety", then you can ask a better question.

Comment: can you please give me some kind of code? It's a bit urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes.

You want to know *how?* That could be a book-level topic. The in-built methods call on the operating system to do the locking and unlocking, and the details will depend on which operating system the Python interpreter is running on.  The operating system will use specialized hardware instructions, and the details of *that* will depend on which hardware platform the OS was built for.

If you want to write your own code to do the same, it won't be Python code: You'll have to write a [Python extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html). I've never done it myself, so I can't tell you any more.

If you want to know more about how locking works *in general,* here's one book that might help: [https://www.amazon.com/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/dp/0123973376/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376)

If you want to know more about any particular operating system or any particular hardware platform, then you will have to consult the appropriate reference manuals.